# Git: Please tell me who you are

Tags: windows, git

I opened my repository in the Git Gui for Windows, and pressed commit. I got

> Unable to obtain your identity:
>
> Please tell me who you are [...] fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'foo@int123123.(none)')

where I anonymized the email address.

However, I had already set up the email address globally using the git console (for windows). To check, I directed myself into the repository folder and entered

```
git config --list
```

and the output was

```
user.name=myName
user.mail=myMail
```

again anonymized, where `myMail` strictly is not `foo@int123123`. What am I to do?

Comment: Did you clone a new repository? If you cloned a new one sometimes it requires you to reconfigure.

Comment: @AndreFerraz Nope, re-entering the config commands did not help

Comment: Does git commit work from within a terminal ?

Comment: You should set a value for the user.email='oyur email', not user.mail

Answer (score 13):

In git console make the following changes,

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"

$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Now, try commit!

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial I followed wrongly informed me to setup `user.mail`. In fact, it is `user.email`. Something not to be spotted quickly in the end of a long day.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem when pushing to Git, the first time, I created a Personal Access Token (PAT) via this link https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token and it worked fine for me.

So instead of working with GitHub password, I work with PAT.